# Error when trying to do 'expo build:android'

Tags: react-native, expo, npm-install, package.json

In the Terminal I get the following error after running the `expo build:android` command:

> ```
> Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
> Error: react-native is not installed. Please run `npm install` or `yarn` in your project directory.
> There is an error with your project. See above logs for information.Error: There is an error with your project. See above logs for information.
> ```

[Terminal error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Px8.png)

I have already tried to update npm version, `npm install`, and I also tried `npm install -g eas-cli`

Are there certain steps anyone thinks I should do?

Comment: Post the output of npm install command.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below guide

1. Delete `node_modules` folder in root folder
2. `npm install` (If you are using **yarn** use `yarn install`)